# VB.NET ERROR for Displaying data in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the sql query to display data from datagridview but i'm having some error

```
 Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT concat( firstname, " ", mname," ", lastname ) AS 
 Fullname, status, member_since FROM userinfo", connection)
```

but this error show "comma,')' or a valid expression continuation expected" sorry I'm new to visual basic

Comment: The last string has to be on *one* line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double quotes (") within a string unless you escape them. But the easier fix to your syntax issue is to use single quotes (') for the space characters between name parts:

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT CONCAT( firstname, ' ', mname, ' ', lastname ) AS Fullname, status, member_since FROM userinfo", connection)
```